# Cannot be converted to JSON

Tags: java, android, json

I am reading some JSON from with in an Android App, yet it will not recognise the following JSON

```
{"value":"1000","make":"Ford","model":"Focus","desc":"1.9 Zetec","Fuel":"petrol"}
```

This is output generated from a PHP file on a webserver. Is there something wrong with this JSON or is the problem with the following code?

```
try {
  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
  JSONObject json_data=null;
  for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String car_value = json_data.getString("value");
    Log.e("JSON",car_value);
  }
} catch (JSONException  e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If you're going to parse a lot of json I recommend having a look at Jackson or Gson they make it a lot easier..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The json data you are receiving is not a JSONArray. It is a JSONObject. So, you should receive it as:

```
JSONObject jArray = new JSONObject(result);
```

And then if you want value you can get it like

```
String car_value = jArray.getString("value");
```

Answer (score 4):

Given String is not a Json Array. That is Json Object. So parse with Json object.

like below

```
try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String value = jObject.getString("value");
            String make = jObject.getString("make");
            // TODO and so on
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```